# Sybase ASE 12.5 database : arabic data shown in latin letters

Tags: sybase, arabic, sap-ase

Good day,

i have a Sybase ASE 12.5 database on windows NT server
the database default charachterset is CP850

i'm trying to connect to it using "TOAD for sybase" ,which is on my windows 7 machine
whatever character set i choose for TOAD (utf8,cp1256..), the data are shown in latin letters instead of arabic

i tried disabling the "server character set conversion" ,and disabling the client side conversion,but still no hope

any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

CP850 is the character set for Western Europe, so that would explain the latin.  If the character set used by the client does not match what is used in the server, then it defaults to English.

You need to change the character set of the server to match what you wish to use for the client, or install the UTF character set in the Server to allow Unicode use.

The [Sybase ASE](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1570/html/sag1/X60641.htm) documentation explains the details of charactersets.

Comment: thank you ,
should adding a character set like CP1256 to the server help?
i tried it ,but still seeing Latin letters ,so gave up this approach

Comment: and another curious question, how can Sybase server store Arabic data while its default charset is CP850?

Comment: Unicode is already installed in syscharsets,also i loaded UTF8 charset with binary sort order (although the default is still cp850 , i can't change it).

i tried TOAD & sql developer again (using utf8), both gets weird characters.

i tried them again using (cp1256),it didn't help.

i made sure "unicode conversion" is enabled.

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

the problem were in the server itself, it was corrupted during cloning.
thanks for all the answers